# Using OR Operator for File Dependencies

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I want to add the file dependency to a job. Suppose there are 2 files

1 : Test.Pdf
2 : Test.xml

Whenever there is either of the file(any one of the file or both) the job should trigger.

I tried multiple qualifiers but not getting the desired result.

Qualifiers that I have tried so far :

A)`-w %p/I%DATE:~12,2%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%*Test.xml || *Test.Pdf`

B)`-w %p/I*Test.xml || *Test.Pdf`

C)`-w %p/I*Test.xml || /I*Test.Pdf`

D)`-w %p/I*Test.xml || -w %p/I*Test.Pdf`

Can anyone let me know how to add the OR Dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file dependencies are actually running `test <qualifier>` command, replacing %p with the filename in qualifier.

This should work for you scenario:
OPENS "/tmp" (-w %p/Test.xml -o -w %p/Test.Pdf)

Comment: Hi Franco,

I tried the qualifiers provided by you :  (-w %p/Test.xml -o -w %p/Test.Pdf)
They are working only when both file names are same.
Is there any way i can use the dependency to check files with different names?
I tried this : (-w %p/*.xml* -o -w %p/*.pdf*) but it isn't working.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ShaikShahabuddin can you provide the name of the files you are trying to test?

Comment: The file names are not constant,they differ for each file.Only common thing in them is the extension .pdf/.xml. So whenever we have a .pdf file or a .xml file our job should trigger.

Comment: @ShaikShahabuddin I've verified that (-w %p/*.xml -o -w %p/*.pdf) works resolving the dependency either if an .xml file is present or a .pdf is present in the `<filename>` directory